# C++ How can i remove the last comma?

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    

    int main() {
      string x;
      cin >> x;
      char ch;
     
/* how can i remove the last comma? */
      int l = x.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        ch = x.at(i);
        cout << ch << ",";}
      return 0;
    }
```

I expect:
    input: 1234
    output: 1,2,3,4
    
    but now:
    input: 1234
    output: 1,2,3,4,

Comment: Do not print the comma on the last iteration.

Comment: Hint: use a `if` statement.

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. Check `if (i != l-1)`, if `true` append/print the comma, otherwise don’t append/print anything.

Comment: How about you print the comma only if i < l-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this(Basically you print the comma separately between that you check if it is the last iteration and works for any numbers):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string x;
  cin >> x;
  char ch;
 
/* how can i remove the last comma? */
  int l = x.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    ch = x.at(i);
    
    cout << ch ;
    if (i==l-1) {break;}
    cout << ",";}
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just print the first char and then print all the other elements preceeded by a comma. You need to deal with the special case of the empty string of course:

```
if (!x.empty())
{
    std::cout << x[0];
    for (auto pos = x.begin() + 1; pos != x.end(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << ',' << *pos;
    }
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a fun solution with c++ views :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::string input("1,2,3,4,5,");

    for(const auto c : input | 
        std::views::reverse | // start looking from back of string
        std::views::drop_while([](const char c) { return c == ','; }) | // drop all characters from the start that are commas
        std::views::reverse // then look over the reverse of the reverse.
        )
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But more in line with your original code.
And not using "using namespace std", and using a range based for loop.
Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/7WmSDm9Do

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  std::string x{"12345"};
  //std::cin >> x;
  
  bool print_a_comma{false};
  for(const auto c : x )
  {
      // adjusted logic, only print a comma before next output if needed
      if ( print_a_comma ) std::cout << ", ";
      std::cout << c;
      print_a_comma = true;
  }
  return 0;
}
```